# Azure Installing Pandas Module

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to install Pandas on my Azure App Service (running Flask) for a long time now but nothing seems to work.

I tried to use wheel, created a wheelhouse directory manually and tried to install the relevant Pandas .whl file (along with its dependent packages) but it still doesn't work. This approach gives me the following error -

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"
"No matching distribution found for ..."

A simple "pip install pandas" also doesn't work - when I do this, in my Kudu Bash client the command gets stuck on "Cleaning up.." and nothing gets installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the SSH terminal instead of the Kudu terminal. I find no reason why it was not working in the Kudu Remote Execution terminal, but using "pip install pandas" in Azure's SSH terminal solved it.